# "Unable to load dynamic library " error when trying to run curl with PHP

Tags: php, curl

I ran :

```
sudo apt-get install curl libcurl3 libcurl3-dev php5-curl
```

Put:

```
extension=php_curl.so
```

in both /etc/php5/cli/php.ini and /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

But running php from the command line gives me the following error:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 
'/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/php_curl.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/php_curl.so:     
cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

Running the install commands again tells me that everything is already the newest version.

Running:

```
locate php_curl.so
```

Returns nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I removed:

```
extension=php_curl.so
```

from both php.ini files and I no longer get the error.